# How to set fetch="Join" and lazy="False" in <key-many-to-one > mapping in hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, hibernate-mapping, many-to-one

I have table mapping in .hbm.xml file as follows. when i set lazy loading to false , it is not working.  It is fire lots of select query to db to load other table.

```
<class name="GroupConfigDO" table="GROUP_CONFIG" >
   <composite-id  >
    <key-property name="Group" column="group" type="java.lang.String"  />
    <key-many-to-one name="Method" column="method"  class="MethodDO" lazy="false" />
        <key-property name="entityId" column="entity_id" type="java.lang.String" /> 

</composite-id>
```

How can i provide fetch type to join and lazy loading to false?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
fetch="select|subselect|join|batch"
```

and select appropriate association that you required

Comment: I have tried this but getting error attribute fetch is not defined for  key-many-to-one.

Comment: Dear Shreyansh , It is inside to composite key , so it not work without key.